# CSS not loading properly in Chrome, double image on the corner of screen

Tags: css

This is regarding a landing page with a full screen image background.

[link to Codepen project](https://codepen.io/kravmaguy/pen/bZNOjx)
On this pen to replicate the problem, resize your browser screen to a mobile width and hover over the text 'leasing' you will notice a large gap on the bottom of the screen.
I tried to solve this using the following styles:

```
      html, body {
      background-image: url("https://greatofficespaces.net/wp- 
      content/uploads/2019/02/Skokie_Warehouse_For_Lease_Promo.jpg");

      /* Full height */
      height: 100vh; 
      width: 100vw;

      /* Center and scale the image nicely */
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover; 
      }
```

When I run this as a local file, instead of a gap on the bottom 
there is a doubling of the image at the edge of the browser screen. Also in chrome browser the css is not loading in as it should
and there is a flash of plain black text for a few seconds until the css loads in.

I read about techniques for image optimization on stacked overflow and having different image files for different media queries and srcset, but I do not think its related to that, I think its a bug somewhere in the css.

Here is the full page
https://github.com/KravMaguy/flyer1

Any help on how to fix these css bugs is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't see any "double image"

Comment: On codepen you will see a small gap at the bottom if you resize your browser to a mobile width. If you download the github project I linked an run it locally and play with the screen resizing it on chrome, you will see the glitch at the corners of the browser but you have to look closely. There is also the issue of the css not loading properly in chrome and an ugly flash of black text before it loads the css. fork the github repo and notice the text 'Leasing' as it first loads on chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by changing it to the following css :

```
  html {
  background-image: url("https://greatofficespaces.net/wp- 
  content/uploads/2019/02/Skokie_Warehouse_For_Lease_Promo.jpg");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100vw;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
  }
```

specifically removing the word 'body'
the previous css class of body, html {styles etc...} applied the same styles to both the html and the body, When I removed one of them I no longer saw the double image in the corner of the browser, implying that the background was assigned to both the html and the body, producing the doubled image and incorrect css loading. This is my guess as to why this was happening and has been resolved.